# Build .apk from app on android device

Tags: android

I am wondering if it is possible to build an .apk-file from an app on my android device, meaning the apk will build and install itself on my phone for instance.

This has to be done without any USB-cables etc!

Best regards

Comment: Take a look at [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

First question: You dont wanna build an apk form existing app, do you?

However, if you have Eclipse, what so ever, on your computer and made the apk file, you can transmit it by e.g by wlan to your smartphone and install it. Beginners could do it like this:

1. Copy the APK file to your Android’s memory card
2. Download and install the Apps Installer application from the Android Market
3. Once installed, the Apps Installer will display the APK files on your memory card.
4. Click and install your APK files.

Else i guess you need a rooted smartphone to it by hand.

Comment: No, I don't wanna build the apk from the existing app.

Let's say I've got this painting/drawing app on my phone, and instead of saving the picture as a picture into the gallery, I want to save it as an apk directly on the phone.

Comment: than you have to change the apps source code and rebuild the app

Answer (score 0):

You could use an app like [Apk Share](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.newpower.apkmanager&hl=en) to backup apps if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, only AIDE and APDE has managed to successfully done this. I am also looking for a solution to do it, and here's what I found(similar questions on Stackoverflow also didn't get answer):

1. You might want to cross compile the toolchain itself.
2. Or you can use a web server that's running linux to compile the apk

So far similar questions only get answers like: hey use AIDE, which is not the answer, here we're looking how to make something like AIDE, not using it. So either cross compile or use a web-based compiler. I haven't found any other solutions